# Как правильно написать фильтр текста

Tags: python, re

Нужна помощь: нужно отфильтровать список с текстом, который будет через итератор отправляться в переводчик, но периодически попадают строки, в которых есть знаки, но нет текста. И если его отправить в переводчик, то произойдет ошибка. Нужно, чтобы сохранились только те элементы, которые содержат в себе текст, при этом не навредив знакам. Например:

```py
compile = re.compile("\w")
chapter = list(filter(compile.match, oldchapter))
```

Но в таком случае сохраняются только те элементы, которые содержат в себе текст, но если там буду знаки то пропускаются

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно просто заменить `match()` на `search()`, поскольку `match()` сравнивает строку с шаблоном с начала строки, а `search()` - с любого места строки.

```
compile = re.compile("\w")
oldchapter = ['! abra kadabra !', '@ # $', 'всякая всячина', '%$%$%']
chapter = list(filter(compile.search, oldchapter))
print(chapter)
```

```
['! abra kadabra !', 'всякая всячина']
```

Answer (score 0):

Считываете построчно текст?

Не совсем понятна проблема: анализируйте своей регуляркой строку и если в ней есть текст, то отправляйте ее целиком в переводчик со всеми "знаками" без фильтрации.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).